# Relay fetchQuery: How to get result of query without fragment structure

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

Let's say I've got a top-level query and a sub-component with a fragment like follows:

```
export const HomePageQuery = graphql`
    query HomePageQuery {
        viewer {
            ...SubComponent_viewer
        }
    }
`

// then a sub-component with
const SubComponentWithFragment = createFragmentContainer(SubComponent, {
    viewer: graphql`
        fragment SubComponent_viewer on Viewer {
            me {
                someImportantValue
            }
        }
    `
})
```

I want to call `HomePageQuery` imperatively, and then once I get the result do something with `someImportantValue`.

So I tried this:

```
// This is a Relay Environment using react-relay-network-modern w/ some middleware
// can give implementation details if required but didn't think necessary
import relayEnv from 'Relay/createRelayEnvironment'

const data = await fetchQuery(relayEnv.environment, HomePageQuery, {})
console.log(data)
```

This then returns me the result, but still broken down into fragments. e.g.

```
{ viewer:
   {
    __fragments: {SubComponent_viewer: {…}}
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the response from this as you'd find in graphiQL? e.g.

```
{
  viewer: {
    me: {
       someImportantValue: 39
    }
  }
}
```

I *could* try and navigate my way through the fragments to find what I need, but this seems over-complicated and would be fragile to changes in component structure.

Is my only option to fetch it from the local store afterwards?

Currently using Relay v7

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to semi-answer this...

You can use the `@inline` directive in [Relay](https://relay.dev/docs/en/graphql-in-relay#inline) to allow you to retrieve the unmasked result.

This didn't *quite* solve my particular use-case, as I want the query itself to remain masked, but get the unmasked result when I call `HomePageQuery` imperatively. But if you don't have this requirement it should work.